# How to implement top slide down drawer in android?

Tags: android

There is an Android application : https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.microsoft.androidapps.picturesque&hl=en that has a slide down drawer. How to implement it ?

I searched online and there is a SlidingDrawer that seems to be depricated.

I dont want activity based solution, but a view based solution. Also, I am trying to avoid the dynamic calculation of view height.

Any suggestions ?